# Flip a div 180 degrees using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to flip a div 180 degrees using a javascript function which triggers a css animation. My div has got the following declaration:

```
.start-photo-thumb
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #444444;
    height: 192px;
    width: 192px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    animation: rotating 0.6s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rotating 
{
    from
    {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to
    {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
```

I think I'm taking the wrong way with my attempt.

```
function flipPhoto(box)
{
    $('#' + box.id).css('animation-play-state', 'running');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#' + box.id).css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
    }, 600);
}
```

In addition I want to change the background-image at the moment you can't see the div (at 90 degrees or at 300ms).

Is there a better and easier way to solve that problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

CSS3 Rotate transformation can be used for flipping any element across x or y axis.

**CSS:**

```
#container_2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

to rotate a div on y-axis use negative values

```
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

---

Above Transformation can also be timed to run after predefined interval using CSS3 animation and Keyframes:

```
@keyframes rotating 
{
    from
    {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to
    {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
 }

 #timed-animation{
    -webkit-animation: rotating 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    rotating 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      rotating 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         rotating 5s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
 }
```

---

Triggering Rotate transformation on click event using jquery

**jQuery:**

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
  $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
  $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

Css Way : http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/x6v60t2f/

Jquery way : http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/LTNPs/2108/

*Reference for CSS3 "transform" article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/*

Comment: I want to do a card flip on the y-axis and I want to use javascript to start the animation on demand

Comment: well you can use `:rotateY(...)` for rotating in y axis

Comment: And how I'm supposed to trigger the animation with javascript? That's the actual problem. Look at my code - I'm already using rotateY()

Comment: @user2655665: could you create a jsfiddle buddy based on your current code , i`ll try fixing it .

Comment: @user2655665 :  Dude i know its been a long time  since you had asked for the solution, but anyway i have added the code for running animation in timed manner :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using only CSS3:

```
div#div-id {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

if you want to animate it you can use CSS3 [animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: I don't know if you even read his question but he uses CSS3 rotation and animation.

Comment: I want to trigger about 15 divs successively with random intervals (between 30 and 150ms)